# Xcode create shared framework across lots of targets

Tags: xcode

I'm making stuff for IOS, Mac, and WatchOS - I have certain common functionality that is more about me and the way I program than about whatever it is I'm programming - helper methods etc

What I'd like is to have a "Common" framework or library in my app which is included into every other library. I understand I need a separate target for each of ios, macos, watchos, but I can't figure out how to set it up.

I can create a framework - and it comes with a target - I can duplicate that target and change stuff, but I don't seem to be able to change it from IOS to macos for instance.   I can create a separate macos target, but then I can't seem to be able to change where it gets the code from.

Essentially in my source tree I want a single directory:
Common

and then have target frameworks CommonIOS, CommonMacOs, CommonWatchOS - that all just compile "Common".   How do I achieve that?

Comment: You need to build a FAT framework.

Comment: I just read about it - I don't think that's what I want - that seems to be a single binary composed of n smaller binaries?   What I'm looking for is purely a compile time thing - I want to create targets a, b, c which all just point to exactly the same source directory.

Comment: actually, investigating further, I don't even want that - all I want to know is how targe membership relates to a group.  I don't want separate targets for "common" - I just want everything I put in "common" to automatically be a member of every target.

Comment: You're the one who said framework. Now it seems that isn't what you mean at all. If you just want to share source code, simply share it. Code itself has no system! Code can be part of any target, and can be part of multiple targets. Just check those boxes! If you want to centralize your code for ease of maintenance across many projects from now on, put it in a Swift package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misusing the word "framework". All you want is to keep some source code as a library that all your projects and targets, no matter what system they'll be compiled for, can use. You are describing a Swift package.

Comment: thanks - that's exactly what I needed - I'd never heard of a swift package before

Comment: You might want to watch https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/410/